# Why not structurally distinguish a predicative complement from an object in a tree diagram?

Tags: syntax-trees

In Dependency and/or Constituency Grammar, I think you get the same tree diagram for Sentence 1 comprising Subject - Verb - Object (*I hit him.*) and Sentence 2 comprising Subject - Verb - Predicative Complement (*I am angry.*).

Am I right?

If so, how come you end up with the same diagram for two different structures?

For examples of tree diagrams in Dependency Grammar and Constituency Grammar, here's an image borrowed from [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_grammar):
[image: Tree diagram examples]

Comment: What diagram are you talking about?  ("I am angry" doesn't have a verb, since "am" is only an auxiliary.)

Comment: @Greg Lee Whatever diagram, I guess. I don't think it's an auxiliary, I think it's a copula or a linking verb.

Comment: Until you can say what diagram you mean, your question will remain uninterpretable.

Comment: You asked "If so, how come you end up with the same diagram for two different structures?"  I'm asking you what "the same diagram" is.  What is this diagram that "I hit him" and "I am angry" have in common?

Comment: @Greg Lee In the example Dependency diagram shown above, simply take the three nodes representing "We", "are" and "trying", and replace each word with "I", "hit" and "him," respectively. And you get a Dependency diagram for "I hit him." Now, take the same three nodes and replace each word with "I", "am" and "angry", respectively, and you get a Dependency diagram for "I am angry." So you end up with the same diagram for Sentences 1 and 2, which are structurally different. The same can be said about Constituency diagrams.

Comment: Well, you're still not telling me what this "same diagram" is.  Are you calling the "diagram" just the branching structure, without the names of the nodes?  If so, why is it a problem to have different structures with the same branching?  (I have previously tried and failed to make sense of Tim Osborne's notion of Constituency grammar/diagram, so I guess I'm not going to be able to answer your question.)

Comment: @Greg Lee Yes, I'm calling the branching structure the diagram. I don't have an answer to why it's a problem (or not a problem) to have different structures with the same branching, because that's precisely what my question is all about. I do understand that tree diagrams can be accompanied with some node names and stuff but the gist of the tree diagram, I think, should be the tree structure itself, and I was asking why you have the same tree structure for clearly different sentence structures.

Comment: In my opinion, you've answered your question.  Different sentence structures may have the same branching, so the stuff at the tree nodes must be part of the structure.

Comment: @Greg Lee But in Dependency Grammar you don't normally have any node annotations, do you?

Comment: I look at your diagrams and see stuff at the nodes.  There are words there.  Look, I don't do this sort of grammar, and I don't understand the point of it.  I don't think there is a point, actually, so I'm not going to be able to explain it.

Answer (score 1):

I will try to answer the question from the phrase structure/constituency grammar perspective.

Assuming that you are asking:

- Is there a structural difference between sentences like 1. and 2.?

  1. 'I am angry.'
  2. 'I hit him.'
- Specifically, is there a difference between predicates like 'angry' and direct objects like 'him', in sentences like those?

The answer is currently believed to be yes. Broad stroke derivations below:

If you're familiar with bracket notation, 1. starts out as:
VP: [hit him]
and proceeds as:
vP: [I [hit him]]

Whereas 2. starts out as:
XP: [I angry]
and proceeds as:
VP: [BE [I angry]]
Finally:
TP: [I [am [t angry]]]

So although your two sentences look similar "on the surface", they're not structurally similar in the parts you seem to be interested in:

- The category of the predicate vs. the direct object,
- The properties of the inflected verb,
- The configuration between subject and predicate, and subject and direct object.

This article by Lohndahl (2006) could be helpful:
http://lohndal.com/wp-content/uploads/copula06.pdf